# Makefile object lists and object locations

Tags: makefile

I have my object files compiled into a specific location using these variables and targets:

```
OBJDIR=./obj

objdir:
    $(MKDIR) $(OBJDIR)

%.o: %.cpp objdir
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $(OBJDIR)/$@
```

Now my problem is, when it comes to linking the executable, I want to use variables to hold the lists of object files, such as:

```
FOOOBJECTS=foo.o foo1.o foo2.o
BAROBJECTS=bar.o bar1.o

mycrappyprogram: main.o $(FOOBOJECTS) $(BARBOJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(FOOBJECTS) $(BAROBJECTS) -o $(BINDIR)/mycrappyprogram
```

Of course I can't do this because all the objects are in `./obj/` so the recipe can't find them.

How can I define a list of object files once, and have them be qualified when used in the recipe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Make can manipulate strings:

```
FOOOBJECTS=foo.o foo1.o foo2.o
BAROBJECTS=bar.o bar1.o

OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(FOOOBJECTS) $(BAROBJECTS))
```

2) Automatic variables are your friends (and I presume you want your executable to incorporate `main.o`, and not just the `foo` and `bar` objects):

```
mycrappyprogram: main.o $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $^ -o $(BINDIR)/$@
```

3) A (non-PHONY) rule should build *the very thing it says it will build*, or you'll get into trouble:

```
$(BINDIR)/mycrappyprogram: main.o $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp objdir
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: I have `VPATH=$(SRCDIR):$(OBJDIR):$(BINDIR)` which I thought would circumvent having to use `$(OBJDIR)/%.o`? But yeah good advice.

Comment: Also, if I have an intermediate target as a prereq (such as for making a directory), I can't use $^ can I? e.g. `$(BINDIR)/myprog: bindir main.o foo.o bar.o`

Comment: ahh I think I have it... in that case `bindir` would be an order-only target (`myprog: main.o foo.o bar.o | bindir`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addprefix`.

```
FOO_DIR       = ./obj/
FOO_OBJS_NAME = foo.o foo1.o foo2.o
FOO_OBJS      = $(addprefix $(FOO_DIR), $(FOO_OBJS_NAME))
```